# Generic/configurable Android app to share browser URLs to website/api

Tags: android, sharing, url

Nearly every link shortener and bookmarking service has their own android application.

What they basically do is adding an entry to the share menu and then do a HTTP request that includes the share URL they got.

Is there a generic Android app that I can use to share URLs to my own web application? There would need to be a way to configure the URL that gets called, and maybe HTTP authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Send2URL](https://github.com/matgoebl/Send2URL) is what I need - lets you configure a remote URL and POSTs the shared data to it.

It [doesn't support sharing URLs](https://github.com/matgoebl/Send2URL/issues/2) from the browser yet, but that will be hopefully fixed soon.